# Unity game view too dark on runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple game menu in unity, but it's looking way too dark in the game view (and in runtime), I tried:

Window->Rendering->Lightning Settings and set the Environment Lightning's Source to color and Light Grey color, also checked the Auto Generate option in Lightmapping settings but nothing of the above worked, it still looks way too dark. Is there any fix for this?

[image: Scene]

[image: Game]

Sorry for the small image in the first link but I think it's very noticeable the difference in the colors anyway.

Comment: I e seen similar in one of my projects. As an example on my pc and chrome my webgl game seems dark but dark like I meant it. If I load it on a Mac it’s as dark as a badgers butt. Not all systems seem to work with the same lighting. It’s therefore something we need to allow for

Comment: Is it a canvas image? What material is it using?

Comment: I can see that you are using only canvas nothing else, in this scene, This should not be the case where you need light for canvas. try using any directional light, that may solve your problem. ```Right-click on hierarchy->Light->Directional Light```

Comment: Is this by any chance occurring when you're switching between one scene and another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scene tab, you have to check the little sun ☼ next to the "Shaded" drop down so as to see the real lightning of your scene.

Since you have no light in your scene (except the ambient one) your models look very dark. Add a directional light to your scene (GameObject > Light > Directional Light)

Comment: my environment lightning source is color, not skybox

Comment: does this help?

Comment: nope, looks exactly the same even with the directional light

Comment: also when i check that little sun the scene looks exactly the same as well

Comment: Gamma has a non-linear approach to light intensity and as such you may see inconsistent colors coming through. Some areas may be brighter, others darker. Linear, as the name implies does utilize a linear approach to light intensity and will result in more realistic looking lighting and colors. Some platforms are restricted to Gamma color space, while others can utilize Linear.  Below is an example of the same scene utilizing a different color space. 
You can find this setting by going into  Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings

Comment: did that help you?

Comment: yeah, it's fixed

Comment: what helped you or what have you done ?, and nice :)

Comment: my settings had the gamma color space, changing it to linear fixed it